# MSE of Non-parametric Regression (Theoretically)

Tags: self-study, smoothing, nonparametric-regression

I'm working through *Computational Statistics, Second Edition* by Givens and Hoeting and I cannot reproduce a result stated in the book. We're considering a nonparametric regression problem where the model of interest is of the form $Y_i=s(x_i)+\varepsilon_i$. Where $s(x_i)=E[Y|X=x_i]$ and $\varepsilon_i$ are zero mean stochastic noise. The book states that the residual mean square error is equal to

$$E\bigg[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\hat{s}(x_i))^2}{n}\bigg]=Var(Y|X=x_i)+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[(\hat{s}(x_i)-s(x_i))^2]}{n}-\frac{\sum_{i\neq j}Cov(Y_i,\hat{s}(x_j))}{n}$$

My attempt at recreating these results was to add and subtract $s(x_i)$ within the parentheses on the left hand side of the above expression. However I get the last term as being

$$-2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Cov(Y_i,\hat{s}(x_i))}{n}$$

If anyone could suggest another way to look at this problem I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Using an informative title will attract more readers!